# Why can't I see CloudWatch Logs for Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I wanted to be able to monitor logs in Cloudwatch when my Lambda being executed, currently there is a section on the top of Lambda console:

[image]

It's showing me any error I got when the Lambda is being executed, but if I click on `logs`, it will direct me to CloudWatch and showing me `log group does not exist`, does anyone know why and how I'll be able to see the logs in Cloudwatch? (I thought it'll be automatical...)

Comment: Can you show if the function even starts or it crashed before your code being run ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your AWS Lambda function needs the following permissions to access CloudWatch Logs:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This will give it permission to create a log group and store events in the log group.

The easiest way to assign this permission is by adding the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` managed policy to the IAM Role being used by your Lambda function.

Answer (score 4):

The most common cause of this problem is that you have not assigned an IAM role to your Lambda function that has permission to create logs in CloudWatch.

Comment: I think it should be automatic, but I couldn't get it in cloudwatch, but I got the logs after I added the lambda permission.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add action

```
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
```

to your lambda role policy

Answer (score -1):

Your log group should be created automatically.

If you click on details arrow you will see the reason it failed, probably it crashed.

I suppose you got a lambda runtime error, before your handler is run.